# Conditional styling not applied when used with ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

I need to use italic font style for the item name when props.itemId == 0.

None of the following 3 options seem to be working

```
<TableCell size={"small"} className={classes.row} style={{fontStyle: props.itemId === 0 ? "italic" : "inherit"}} > { props.itemId === 0 ? "Item Deleted" : props.itemName } </TableCell>


{ props.itemId === 0 ? 
    <TableCell size={"small"} className={classes.row} > <i> "Item Deleted" </i></TableCell>
    :
    <TableCell size={"small"} className={classes.row}  >{props.itemName}</TableCell>
}


{ props.itemId === 0 ? 
  <TableCell size={"small"} className={classes.row} style={{fontStyle: "italic"}} > "Item Deleted" </TableCell>
  :
  <TableCell size={"small"} className={classes.row}>{props.itemName}</TableCell>
}
```

With the first option the font-style always ends up as 'inherit', even though it correctly displays Item Deleted or props.itemName depending on the condition.

Same for the other two, italic is not applied, but the name is correctly displayed depending on props.itemId being zero or not.

For the life of me I can't figure out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @paperskyline, with the last 2 cases italic is not there at all. For the first option it just ends up as 'inherit' always.

Comment: the first line seems wrong. shouldn't the content inside TableCell be inside curly braces?

Comment: @paperskyline it should yeah, sorry for that. It's updated now, but issue still persists.

Comment: Have you checked that `itemId` is actually `0`? Perhaps it's being passed in as e.g. `"0"`/`null`/`undefined` etc.